# Node/Express: Render value taken from postgres via SELECT statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I'm trying to render a value from a postgres db from a SELECT statement in my index view (written in EJS):

***routes/index.js***:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');

router.use('/subscribe', require('./subscribe.js'));
router.use('/about', require('./about.js'));
let userCount;

db.query(`SELECT count(*) AS exact_count from users`, (error,results) => {
    if (error) {
        //console.log(error.stack)
    } else {
        return userCount = results.rows[0]['exact_count']
        //console.log(userCount)
    }
})

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    //res.send("Hello from your local node server")
    
    res.render('pages/index', {userCount:userCount})
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/pages/index.ejs**:

```
<%- include('../partials/head'); %>
<%- include('../partials/header') %>

<main class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Email List!</h1>
        <p class="lead">Join. The. List.</p>
        <hr class="my-2">
        <p>Keep up to date with our progress!</p>
        <p>We currently have <%= userCount  %> users</p>
        <a href="subscribe" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign up for newsletter</a>
    </div>
    
</main>

<%- include('../partials/footer') %>
```

Things aren't working, how do I get that value to render in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the query returns then render the page.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query(`SELECT count(*) AS exact_count from users`, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      // render error page
      // return res.render('pages/error', { error });
    }
    res.render('pages/index', { userCount: results.rows[0]['exact_count'] });
  });
});
```